# How to create a simple browser-based IRC client?

Tags: irc

I want to implement a chat service on my site, and wonder how to create a simple browser-based IRC client from scratch?

I have a linux box and can install whatever I want on it. Google finds tutors on how to setup an IRC server but no instructions on how to create an IRC client.

(As client languages, I can use JavaScript or Flash.)

Comment: How about embedding a Mibbit instance?

Comment: I would love to develop my own solution. Just need tips on how to get started.

Comment: I think you can not do that kind of thing with JS and Flash, as they both have strong security concepts preventing connections to the outside by default. You might want to look into a CGI/PHP and AJAX mixup.

Answer (score 6):

As you are already familiar with JavaScript, I would recommend a combination of Node.js, Now.js and node-irc.

Node.js is an application that enables you to run JavaScript server-side and to develop web-applications very fast.

[Now.js](http://nowjs.com/) is a library for Node.js that enables you to RPC between client and server. You can just call a function on the server from your client application and vice-versa; their developers guide is in fact a web chat ;)

[node-irc](https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc) is also a library for node.js that enables you to easily create an IRC client.

Combine these three and you get a very nice, very easy self-coded web chat. For the browser interface, there are *many* possibilities, including application frameworks like ExtJS, JQueryUI, KendoUI or something easier.

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.lightirc.com/
- http://wdmedia.org/WFIC/index-en.html#sectiondescription